# Why is Givens better than Householder on sparse matrix?

Tags: matrices

I am trying to transform a matrix from something like

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

to

```
0 b 0
d 0 f 
0 h 0
```

but at a way larger scale. My question is, why exactly is Givens better than Householder, considering their complexities? Can you please,please explain the details to me? I'm having a hard time understanding.Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Householder reflection is better than Givens rotation in dense linear algebra?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227543/why-householder-reflection-is-better-than-givens-rotation-in-dense-linear-algebr)